# Recursively add the entire folder to a repository

Tags: git, github

I am trying to add a branch to the master branch on GitHub and push a folder onto that branch.

The folder structure of the branch looks like -
SocialApp/SourceCode/DevTrunk/SocialApp and all the source code files are in the last folder.

I am using the following Git commands:

```
git add *
git commit -m with the message
git push
```

This is pushing only the first folder "SocialApp" onto GitHub and ignoring the folder SourceCode that is inside the folder. How do I fix this?

Comment: are there files anywhere? aren't they ignored in `.gitignore`?

Comment: `This is pushing only the first folder` - git doesn't care about folders at all, only files. please show the commit - you've either committed a submodule, a symlink or something else that's not a folder

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  I don't think this is a problem but just the expected behavior.  Surprising there are so many solutions.

Comment: note: when your folders are empty they are not tracked. its a good practice to put a empty .keep file in there to keep the empty directories

Answer (score 411, accepted):

Check the `.gitignore` file, if the subdirectory is ignored.

Then try again

```
git add --all
git commit -am "<commit message>"
git push
```

Comment: Note that this will not include files mentioned in .gitignore. I usually add those by hand or use a batch file like this: `for /R %%f in (*.*) do git add --force %%f` (see https://bitbucket.org/jeroenp/besharp.net/src/tip/Scripts/GIT/git-add-force-all-files-recursively-from-current-directory.bat)

Comment: To recursively add the entire tree structure of the folder, the command should be `git add --all :/`

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers `git add -f -all` works to add .gitignored files

Comment: @JasonHartley Your comment could be an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't this add all unstaged files in the git repo, not just the current folder? I don't think it's what the original question is asking.

Comment: I used this while in the directory that I wanted to start adding files and it ended up adding all the files even outside of the directory. Stay away from this solution.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's about adding a folder, not the whole directory tree. Some people don't want to add all because you can accidentally commit unwanted files that way.

Comment: This is a bad solution as other commenters mention. This recursively stages all files in the repo, not the current directory from the command line.

Answer (score 89):

SETUP

- local repository at a local server
- client is connected to the local server via LAN

**UPDATE(Sep 2020):** use `foldername/\*` instead of `foldername/\\*`:

```
git add foldername/\*
```

To make it to the server...

```
git commit -m "comments..."
git push remote_server_name master
```

Mostly, users will assign remote_server_name as origin...

```
git remote add remote_server_name username@git_server_ip:/path/to/git_repo
```

Comment: Failed as `fatal: pathspec 'foldername/\\*' did not match any files`. Worked as `git add foldername/\*`.

Comment: What's the difference between `git add foldername/\\*` and `git add --all`?

Comment: Danijel, the former adds all the files in one folder, whereas the latter adds all files in the repository

Comment: `git add -f foldername/\*` - worked for me. Added `-f`.

Comment: Thanks Andrey Patseiko. The '-f' specifier also worked for me - SourceTree 4.2.5 (259) on Mac OS.

Answer (score 46):

This worked for me:

```
git add . --force
```

Comment: The other answers require the file list to be computed as an argument to the command, this one doesn't, hence is a better choice.

Comment: Definitely the best answer.. One edit would be to mention that you don't need the `--force` if you want the ignores to still be respected.

Answer (score 21):

In my case, there was a .git folder in the subdirectory because I had previously initialized a git repo there. When I added the subdirectory it simply added it as a subproject without adding any of the contained files.

I solved the issue by removing the git repository from the subdirectory and then re-adding the folder.

Comment: This solved it for me. I also had to rename the folder itself for the fix to kick in.

Answer (score 18):

Both "git add *" and "git add SocialApp" called from top directory should add recursively all directories.

Probably you have no files in SocialApp/SourceCode/DevTrunk/SocialApp and this is the reason.

Try to call "touch SocialApp/SourceCode/DevTrunk/SocialApp/.temporary" (and check .gitignore) and then try git add again.

Comment: I don't think so, I use git add * and am having the same issue.

Answer (score 10):

I simply used this:

```
git add app/src/release/*
```

You simply need to specify the folder to add and then use `*` to add everything that is inside recursively.

Comment: This can fail. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084227/gitignore-fatal-no-files-added

Comment: @kmiklas Interesting. Should it be `git add app/src/release/.`?

Comment: ``git add --all app/src/release/`` worked for me; ref: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add

Comment: @kmiklas I like that approach. I will use it next time. It worked for me using `git add app/src/release/*` but if it can fail, why taking risks? I will better use `git add --all app/src/release/` next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this problem that cost me a little time, then remembered that git won't store empty folders.  Remember that if you have a folder tree you want stored, put a file in at least the deepest folder of that tree, something like a file called ".gitkeep", just to affect storage by git.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to add a directory and all the files which are located inside it recursively, Go to the directory where the directory you want to add is located.

```
$ cd directory
$ git add directoryname
```

Comment: cd directory
git add *

Answer (score 7):

**Scenario / Solution 1:**
Ensure your `Folder` / `Sub-folder` is not in the `.gitignore` file, by any chance.

---

**Scenario / Solution 2:**
By default, `git add .` works recursively.

---

**Scenario / Solution 3:**
`git add --all :/` works smoothly, where `git add .` doesn't (work).
*(@JasonHartley's comment)*

---

**Scenario / Solution 4:**
The issue I personally faced was adding `Subfolders or Files`, which were common between multiple `Folders`.

For example:

`Folder/Subfolder-L1/Subfolder-L2/...file12.txt`

`Folder/Subfolder-L1/Subfolder-L2/Subfolder-L3/...file123.txt`

`Folder/Subfolder-L1/...file1.txt`

So `Git` was recommending me to add `git submodule`, which I tried but was a pain.

---

**Finally what worked for me was:**

 1. `git add` one file that's at the last end / level of a `Folder`.

For example:

`git add Folder/Subfolder-L1/Subfolder-L2/Subfolder-L3/...file123.txt`

 2. `git add --all :/` now.

It'll **very swiftly** add all the `Folders`, `Subfolders` and `files`.

---

Answer (score 5):

Navigate to the folder where you have your files
if you are on a windows machine you will need to start git bash from which you will get a command line interface then use these commands

```
git init   //this initializes a .git  repository in your working directory

git remote add origin <URL_TO_YOUR_REPO.git> // this points to correct repository where files will be uploaded

git add *   // this adds all the files to the initialialized git repository
```

if you make any changes to the files before merging it to the master you have to commit the changes by executing

```
git commit -m "applied some changes to the branch"
```

After this checkout the branch to the master branch

Comment: Only answer that mentions `init`

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same issue and I do not have .gitignore file. My problem was solved with the following way. This took all sub-directories and files.

```
git add <directory>/*
```

Answer (score 4):

There are times that I want to include my web service source codes along with its client-side project. Both of them have a separate git repositories.
I am actually used to add all files using the command:

```
git add -A
```

But for some reason, it only adds the folder. Later on I found out that the server files also have its `.git` folder in it so the command doesn't work.

**tl;dr**: Make sure there are no `.git` folder inside the folder you want to stage.

Comment: How can you get around this if you dont want to remove the .git folders?

Comment: @rolls see [git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1811730/2304737)

Answer (score 4):

`git add --all my/awesome/stuff/` works for me. [1]

1. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to do this, and I found that you can easily add files in subdirectories. You only need to be on the "top directory" of the repo, and then run something like:

```
$ git add ./subdir/file_in_subdir.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me

```
git add -f *
```