# In Git, what´s the best strategy when adding files for tracking, new repository?

Tags: git

My scenario:
I have a Visual Studio project that I initialize in Git as a new repository (git init). 
Now I want to specify which files should be tracked (git add). But this command always adds files from every single subfolder. Is there a way to only add (for tracking) files in the present folder without subfolders?
/Mattias

Comment: Use `git add $(find -type f -maxdepth 1)` or `git add FolderName/\*.*`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a .gitignore and add the folders that you don't want to add. Since i'm guessing this is a onetime issue i would dig into that and add there the folders that i dont want.

For example if you'r in the folder foo and it have to subfolders bar1/ and bar2/ you could add those two subfolders to your gitignore. You could use several .gitignores.

```
# Ignore  all subdirectories in this directory using gitignore
*/
# Ignore some subdirectories
bar/
bar2/
```

If you'r standing in the correct directory you could use something like:

```
git add $(find -type f -maxdepth 1)
```

or

```
git add FolderName/\*.*
```

The *.* adds every file from every file type, but directories don't have extensions so they wont be added.

Basically for first project setup it will probably take a little while, but it's worth it.

See also similar thread:
[How to `git add` non-recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663402/how-to-git-add-non-recursively)

For reference on gitignore: 
http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: I cant seem to make the .gitignore file work. The file is positioned in the folder where I run:  git add *.txt
.gitignore has the line:   
bin/
But I still get a .txt file from within bin tracked.

Comment: Try changing bin/ to bin/*.txt or /bin/*.txt
It should work anyways, not sure whats the problem.

Comment: Well, not even adding *.txt makes it ignore txt files in the current directory. My file name is .gitignore, alright. It seems like the whole .gitignore file is ignored. Ironic...

Comment: If you have already added the file to git you need to remove it before the gitignore will work. That might be the problem.

Comment: But I havent. Its a new project not commited yet. Just now I tried this: I have a directory with some files, never commited or anyting. I run git init. I create a .gitignore with one line, orderDB.txt. I then execute git add *.txt. Now I am under the impression that all .txt files should be tracked except the orderDB.txt. But thats not what happens. All txt including orderDB.txt gets tracked. I really dont understand why.