# How to push the entire content of a working tree to a remote branch?

Tags: git, aptible

I'm trying to deploy a Django app using the [Aptible](https://www.aptible.com/) platform by following the instructions on https://www.aptible.com/documentation/enclave/tutorials/quickstart-guides/python/django.html. I currently have two remotes:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$ git remote -v
aptible git@beta.aptible.com:lucy/web.git (fetch)
aptible git@beta.aptible.com:lucy/web.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/startwithlucy/lucy.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/startwithlucy/lucy.git (push)
```

I'm on a branch which is also called `aptible`:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$ git status
On branch aptible
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I would like to push the entire contents of the working tree to the `master` branch of the `aptible` remote. Following [Recursively add the entire folder to a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743549/recursively-add-the-entire-folder-to-a-repository), I tried a `git add --all` followed by a `git commit -a`,

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$ git commit --help
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$ git add --all
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$ git commit -am "Git add --all followed by git commit -am"
[aptible 9ea97969] Git add --all followed by git commit -am
 2 files changed, 9254 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 docker-compose.yml
 create mode 100644 lucy-app/package-lock.json
```

followed by a `git push aptible aptible:master`:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$ git push aptible aptible:master
```

However, this is giving me the following error message from Aptible:

```
remote: ERROR -- : No Dockerfile found. Aborting!
```

There is, however, a `Dockerfile` in the directory:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$ ls Dockerfile
Dockerfile
```

Any idea why this `push` is not working as expected? (I also believe that the project makes use of Git subtrees, though I'm not sure whether this is relevant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man git-commit`:

```
   -a, --all
       Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been
       modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are
       not affected.
```

Basically, when you run `git -am ...`, this only commits files git knows about that you have changes in. However, since you never committed your `Dockerfile`, that does not get included (because git does *not* know abut it).

You can confirm this from the output of `git commit -am`: only `docker-compose.yml` and `lucy-app/package-lock.json` were committed:

```
[aptible 9ea97969] Git add --all followed by git commit -am
 2 files changed, 9254 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 docker-compose.yml
 create mode 100644 lucy-app/package-lock.json
```

Running `git add --all` before running `git commit -am ...` actually has no impact whatsoever: `git add --all` does stage the `Dockerfile`, but when you run `git commit -am ...`, the `Dockerfile` is unstaged.

To fix this, don't use the `-a` flag on `git commit`, like this:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    Dockerfile

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git add --all

$ git commit -m 'Add Dockerfile'
[master 6296160] Add Dockerfile
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 Dockerfile
```

Comment: In addition, I believe there is an Aptible-specific issue at play here (which I hadn't given enough information for): Aptible expects the `Dockerfile` to be in the root of the repository (cf. https://www.aptible.com/documentation/enclave/reference/apps/image/dockerfile-deploy.html), whereas `lucy-web` is actually a subdirectory of the working tree (which is called `lucy`).