# Cannot add node modules to git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have modified some node modules and I want to add them to git but they never get added. My app is running in IntelliJ on a MacBook. I tried all the solutions at:

[Recursively add the entire folder to a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743549/recursively-add-the-entire-folder-to-a-repository/39152450)

to no avail. I have no `.gitignore` file. What is preventing these files from being added? I can even open up a file, make a minor change and save it. Yet Git still does not recognize any changes.

Comment: Are you sure they are not being ignored? Do they show up if you run `git status` ? Usually node modules are set to ignore.

Comment: git status shows them as new files (everything is green) but when I go to do a commit, nothing gets added.

Comment: Can you tell how you add them? and can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: git add some_node_module/. -f

Comment: Please add a screenshot for git status, and also, if you don't have a .gitignore file, the other location which could possibly add an ignore rule is in `.git/info/exclude` please add that file too.

Comment: There appears to be a bug in IntelliJ using the Git menu commands there. I executed the commit command in a terminal instead and this did work. Seems like IntelliJ deliberately prevents committing node files and doesn't even report when they have changed.

Comment: Alright, then I guess it's solved. :)