# Repeated repo import of unversioned directory tree

Tags: git

Given

- An unversioned directory tree with files.
- An empty git repository.

**What's a robust way to repeatedly import the directory tree into the git repo?**

Goals:

- No commit if no changes in directory tree.
- Any file or directory additions/modifications/deletions are committed and pushed.

Sample use case:

- Snapshot unversioned data, could be reports, configuration exports etc.

Assumption:

- Only this process makes changes to the repo, so no merge conflicts possible.

First attempt, based on [Recursively add the entire folder to a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743549/recursively-add-the-entire-folder-to-a-repository):

```
# Here some process makes changes to the directory tree
git add --all
git commit -m "<commit message>"
git push
```

Improvements/remarks are welcome.

Comment: I don't think you need the `-a` flag for commit if you've already run `git add --all`.

Comment: That makes sense, I updated my question