# How to stage all files in if a subfolder on git

Tags: git

May I know how to stage all the files in a folder like a folder called subfolder on git?

Have tried

```
git add subfolder/\\*
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git add all subdirectories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620863/git-add-all-subdirectories)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just use `git add subfolder`.

I usually use `git add .` in the root of the repository to stage all files in the repo.

If you want to use the asterisk, you should use `git add subfolder/*` because the shell will expand this into `git add subfolder/foo subfolder/bar subfolder/...` with all the files in the directory.

When using `git add subfolder/\\*`, the shell won't expand the asterisk, which will cause it to call `git add subfolder/*` which tries to add a file called `*` in the subfolder.