# "git add -all" command not add files under my GitRepository/.vim/subdir/sub-subdir

Tags: git, vim

I just want to sync my .vim folder in every computer I have. Those are what I have done for that purpose: 1. cp -r ~/.vim ~/GitRepository/ 2. cd ~/GitRepository 3. git add --all 4. commit and push. But when I check my github, those files should be under the /.vim/subdir/sub-subdir are missing. And those sub-subdir became empty. What could make this happen, though I don't have a .gitignore file and suggestion in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620863/git-add-all-subdirectories) do no help to me.

And when I type git status. These note show up:

```
─➤  git status

On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

modified:   .vim/bundle/vim-snippets (modified content)
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

what make this happen?

=============== second edit=============
Thank you, guys. "git add -all"actually missed the dot-file I have. But, It don't conquer my problem.

here is what after I type git add .vim/

```
╰─➤  git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   .vim/.netrwhist
    new file:   .vim/.vimrc
    new file:   .vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py
    new file:   .vim/.ycm_extra_conf.pyc
    new file:   .vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
    new file:   .vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
    new file:   .vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim
    new file:   .vim/bundle/molokai
    new file:   .vim/bundle/nerdtree
    new file:   .vim/bundle/tagbar
    new file:   .vim/bundle/ultisnips
    new file:   .vim/bundle/vim-airline
    new file:   .vim/bundle/vim-colorschemes
    new file:   .vim/bundle/vim-fugitive
    new file:   .vim/bundle/vim-json
    new file:   .vim/bundle/vim-snippets
    new file:   .vim/colors/molokai.vim
    new file:   .vim/colors/solarized.vim

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   .vim/bundle/vim-snippets (modified content)
```

It seams that git do not recognize these as a directories, why?

Comment: if you don't have a .gitignore and don't care about any dummy file, you could try `git add . -f`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert between big-endian and little-endian values in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the reason why. I used vundle to manage my vim and .vim/ folder. So, it seams that vundle used the service of git in every "subdir", and with the .gitignore in every "subdir", it actually ignore these things in "subdir".

Answer (score 2):

`add --all` won't add hidden files or directories (i.e. those starting with a dot). You need to add them explicitly by name (or at least a pattern like `.*`).

(Off topic, but possibly helpful: I use [homesick gem](https://github.com/technicalpickles/homesick) for my dotfile management. It automates many of the things you are doing by hand now.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about homesick. But it seams more time to learn about. Could you describe more about "explicitly by name"? Should I type git add manually by name?

Comment: `git add ~/GitRepository/.vim`, if I understood your directory structure correctly.

Comment: Yes, I do exactly what you say. But the problem is still not solved. I edited the Q&A again, it shows the no deference except some dot files under the ~/GitRepository.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a directory and all the files located inside it recursively, you must specify the directory name in the `add` command.

```
$ git add directoryname
```

Comment: No, this is incorrect. Directories can be added using `add --all` without naming them explicitly; *hidden* directories can't.

Answer (score 1):

The best way you can use is :

```
 git add *
```

or

```
 git add <directory name>
```